# In QGIS print composer, pdf in CMY/RGB, dosen't show correct colore after print

Tags: qgis, print-composer, color

By color setting in QGIS, I can **only** set RGB color **but not CMY**, so I've taken the cmy color from FreeHand, converted to RGB in Adobe Photoshop. Then exported the map as PDF (in QGIS). Before printing this PDF, I've controlled the color using of Adobe Photoshop, it shows me wrong cmy. Is this the problem with a printer or it is possible to get correct cmy or rgb color before print?

Comment: Which 'Mode' and 'Bit Depth' do you use while opening PDF in Photoshop?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Merhaba, 'Mode':RGB, 'Bit Depth': 8 bit

Comment: I guess it's not about QGIS and after opening PDF in Photoshop, changing image mode to 'CMYK Color' (Image > Mode > CMYK color) will fix CMYK values, but will  naturally change RGB values.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz So then how I will print my map with correct RGB color? because the color after printing(was actually already converted from cmy to rgb) shows me different. The problem is not the Photoshop i think personally. i just wanted to print my map in cmyk, or in correct rgb color.

Comment: What do you mean with "Print", exporting map to PDF or printing PDF on a paper?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz exporting the map as pdf and printing this map(PDF) on a paper with cmyk. I've changed the mode to CMYK but still with the wrong color.